# Add a pattern before the delimiter

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, csv

I'm looking for a command to add a pattern before or the delimiter.

**My sting:**

```
1 |Chris|ubuntu
```

Here my delimiter is`|` and I want to generate a string with this input.

**Output**

```
1 = ID and Chris = Name and Ubuntu = OS
```

Sometimes, my input has 2 values only.
Let's say `2 | Ram`, which has one value and no delimiter, so it should print:

```
2=ID and Ram=Name
```

So, `field1 + "and" + field2 + "and" + field3`. If field3 is not available in the input string then use `field1 + "and" + field2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F '|' '
            { printf("%d = ID and %s = Name", $1, $2) } 
    NF == 3 { printf(" and %s = OS", $3) }
            { printf("\n") }' file
```

This would generate

```
1 = ID and Chris = Name and ubuntu = OS
2 = ID and  Ram = Name
```

for the given data.  The `awk` code simply inserts the two first fields into the `printf` format template.  If a third field is available, the OS part is then outputted on the same line.  The line is then terminated by a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Hi with Miller http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc, starting from this input file

`1|Chris|ubuntu
2|Ram`

and running

```
mlr --ifs "|" label ID,Name,OS input.csv
```

You will have

`ID=1,Name=Chris,OS=ubuntu
ID=2,Name=Ram`

Answer (score 0):

In `Bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
    printf "Missing argument\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

num_of_delimiters="$(grep -o '|' <<< "$1" | wc -l)"
sting="$(sed -E 's,\s+\|,|,g' <<< "$1")"
sting="$(sed -E 's,\|\s+,|,g' <<< "$sting")"

case "$num_of_delimiters" in
    1)
    echo "$(cut -d '|' -f1 <<< "$sting")"=ID and "$(cut -d '|' -f2 <<< "$sting")"=Name
    ;;
    2)
    echo "$(cut -d '|' -f1 <<< "$sting")" = ID and "$(cut -d '|' -f2 <<< "$sting")" = Name and \
         "$(sed  's/./\U&/' <<< "$(cut -d '|' -f3 <<< "$sting")")" = OS
    ;;
    *)
    printf "More than 2 delimiters or no delimiters\n" >&2
    exit 2
esac
```

It will also print whitespaces as you showed in your example and will
convert the first letter of the third word to uppercase.  Examples:

```
$ ./sting.sh "2 | Ram"
2=ID and Ram=Name
$ ./sting.sh "1 |Chris|ubuntu"
1 = ID and Chris = Name and Ubuntu = OS
```

No errors reported by `https://www.shellcheck.net/`.

Comment: Hey, Im also doing a similar kind of process, But for me the inputs may contains more than 2 delimiters. 
In this case, how can I remove that restriction?